# PostMethod HttpPost HttpClient - post xml with url parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, http-post, httpclient, xml-rpc

Is there a way in java to post an XML using PostMethod or HttpPost along with the url parameters? I am doing something like below, but it is not working.

```
URL - https://mytest.com?z=123&b=abc&c=%10

xml - <test>
        <data> This is test XML </data>
      </test>

public String getResponse(String xml) {

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// "https://mytest.com?z=123&b=abc&c=%10"
String url="https://mytest.com";
PostMethod pMethod = new pMethod(url);
pMethod.addParameter("z","123");
pMethod.addParameter("b","abc");
pMethod.addParameter("c","%10");
post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml, "application/xml", "UTF-8"));
client.executeMethod(pMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a REST client to perform an HTTP POST. Also, you should pass your XML on the body of the POST, and not as a URL parameter (URL encoding problems).

A simple example POSTing a JSON can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I misunderstood your question the first time. You want to pass XML as a URL parameter, but do it via POST rather than just including the XML directly in the URL? You can do it like this:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class XMLPoster {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            String XMLData = argv[0];
            URL url = new URL("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");
            String myParam = "myparam=" + URLEncoder.encode(XMLData, "UTF-8");
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(myParam.length()));
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter((httpConn.getOutputStream())));
            writer.write(myParam, 0, myParam.length());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            System.out.println(httpConn.getResponseCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Then if you run this:

```
$ java -cp . XMLPoster '<ThisXMLisFake>But how do you know?</ThisXMLisFake>'
200
```

and find the corresponding file on posttestserver.com it should contain this, which is hopefully what you want:

```
Post Params:
key: 'myparam' value: '<ThisXMLisFake>But how do you know?</ThisXMLisFake>'
Empty post body.

Upload contains PUT data:
myparam=%3CThisXMLisFake%3EBut+how+do+you+know%3F%3C%2FThisXMLisFake%3E
```

Comment: I don't want to pass XML as parameter. I have different parameters to send along with URL and along with that I need to post XML .

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with built-in Java stuff like so:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class XMLPoster {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            String XMLData = argv[0];
            URL url = new URL("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(XMLData.length()));
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter((httpConn.getOutputStream())));
            writer.write(XMLData, 0, XMLData.length());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            System.out.println(httpConn.getResponseCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This code is of course just an example and doesn't do error checking, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameters to the URL along with the XML?

Comment: This does not include parameters as part of the post.